# swf to video with audio

Tags: flash, mp4, file-conversion

I am developing an app which requires some animated files. I am developing the animations in Adobe Flash Professional CC. However, the output .swf format is not supported in android now a days. Hence, I need to convert the files to a video format, .mp4 preferably. The animation will also contain a sound. The problem I am facing is that, no matter what tools I am using, the converted file does not import the audio. One exception was the Xilisoft converter, which however, extended the length of the video and thus, the audio and video does not synchronize.

Can anyone kindly provide me with an optimal procedure of conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually couldn't find any converter that can do the work successfully. However, I found the alternate through Adobe After Effects. The .swf file and the audio files can be separately imported into a project and can be produced as a combined output. Hope that helps everyone who is facing the problem.